# Apache directory listing not working

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-vista

I've just manually installed **Apache** and **PHP**, and everything is working fine apart from one thing: I can't get a directory listing or open any files. A slight problem.

It works fine if I change my root to the htdocs in my Apache directory, but it refuses to work when I change it to the directory I want.

I've PHP installed in `F:\PHP`, I have Apache installed in `F:\Program Files\Apache`, and my root is `F:\www` (this last thing is the problem).

Here's a snippet of my httpd.conf

```
<Directory "F:/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The directory exists with test.php in it and I get **403 Forbidden** error when I try either.

If I change the line `<Directory "F:/www">` to point to the htdocs directory mention above and restart Apache, it works fine. Why doesn't it like F:/www?

What have I done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Obvious question: did you restart apache after changing the .conf file? And not having ever tried Apache on windows, is the `/` in the path correct? Would a ` \ ` work better?

Comment: @Marc, Yes I've restarted Apache many times.

Comment: Apologies if this is better suited to ServerFault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh. Complete newb error. I tried to delete the question, but it won't let me.

I didn't change `DocumentRoot` in the HTTPD.CONF, I only added a `<directory>` statement.

Now it works fine.

*facepalm*

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have no directive like

```
Options -Indexes
```

and that the module mod_autodindex is loaded (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html)

It may also be due to a parent directory without the Indexes in Options and AllowOverride set to None, like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: Surely changing my root directory wouldn't have an effect if this was the problem?

Comment: Depends on in what order the directives are applied. Later ones will override earlier ones.

Comment: If I literally change that one line in the document to point to a different directory, but change nothing else?